# Does Lebesgue measurable set $E \subset [0,1]$ contain a $G_{\delta}$ set with the same measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset [0,1]$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. It is known that there exists a $G_{\delta}$ set $G \supset E$ such that $m(E)=m(G)$. But my problem is:

> Does $E \subset [0,1]$ Lebesgue measurable set always contain a $G_{\delta}$ subset $G \subset E$ such that $m(E)=m(G)$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a meager set of measure 1, which one can construct in various ways; e.g. [There exist meager subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ whose complements have Lebesgue measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705057/there-exist-meager-subsets-of-mathbbr-whose-complements-have-lebesgue-measu).  If $G \subset E$ is $G_\delta$ then since $G$ is meager, by the Baire category theorem it is not dense.  That means there is some nonempty open $U \subset [0,1]$ with $G \subset [0,1] \setminus U$.  As such, $m(G) \le 1 - m(U) < 1$.