# Meager set on $\mathbb{R}$ whose complement has Lebesgue measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I wish to prove that there exist meager subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ whose complements have Lebesgue measure zero.

Let us first enumerate the rationals by $\{q_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.  My intuition was to cover $\mathbb{R}$ with intervals centered at rational points each with radius say $1/(n2^{k})$ (so the radius depends on which rational the interval is centered at) and call this cover $B_n$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $B_n$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, hence its complement must be nowhere dense and thus meager. Furthermore, the set $B = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$ must also be meager also be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ as it is a countable intersection of dense sets. So it follows that $B^c$ must be meager, and $m(B) \leq m(B_n) = 1/n$.

It appears that by sending $n \rightarrow \infty$ we acheive the desired result, but I was wondering if conceptually this makes sense. As we approach infinity, at some point in the limit would the set $B_n$ no longer be dense?

Also, how do we know $B$ is not empty?

Comment: No. It  will always contain the rational numbers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705057/there-exist-meager-subsets-of-mathbbr-whose-complements-have-lebesgue-measu

Comment: @UmbertoP. Even in that case, how do we know the complement of each $B_n$ or $B$ is not empty?

Comment: I’m not sure how helpful this is, but an equivalent problem is finding a meagre subset of $[0, 1]$ with measure $1$. If we had a meagre subset $V$ of $[0, 1]$ with measure $1$, we would see that $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \{x + n \mid x \in V\}$ is a meagre set whose complement has measure zero. Conversely, given a meagre $V$ whose complement has measure zero, $V \cap [0, 1]$ is meagre with measure 1.

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494705/977780  and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463360/977780 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1705057/977780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some modifications, your procedure can be made rigorous.

Fixed an enumeration $\{q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of a countable dense set $Q$.

Define $U_m = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_{2^{-(n + m)}}(q_n)$. Each $U_m$ is an open set containing $Q$, hence dense. We see that $\mu(U_m) \leq \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty 2^{1 -(n + m)} = 2^{2 - m}$. Let $U = \bigcap\limits_{m \in \mathbb{N}} U_m$; then for all $m$, we have $\mu(U) \leq \mu(U_m) \leq 2^{2 - m}$. Therefore, $\mu(U) = 0$. Since $U$ is the countable union of dense open sets, it is the complement of a meagre set.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any guarantee that $U^c$ is going to be nonempty?

Comment: @CBBAM If $U^c$ were empty, its measure would be zero. Then $\mu(U \cup U^c) = 0$.